# jQuery remove all renditions of class before re-adding the same class to other elements

Tags: jquery, element

Got a jQuery script on a WordPress based project which is to add the class 'formshow' to certain div's. It works, but I also want to remove it from other elements where the 'formshow' class exists first. Tried a bunch of different methods, even ones I found here and nothing is working. Here's a simplified version of my script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var element1 = ['option1','option2','option3'];
    var element2 = ['option2','option3','option4'];
    jQuery('#select-1').change(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() === 'select1' || 'select2') {
            jQuery.each(element1, function (index, elementId) {
                jQuery('#' + elementId).filter('.'+'formshow').removeClass('formshow'); 
                jQuery('#' + elementId).addClass('formshow');
            });
        }
        else if (jQuery(this).val() === 'select3' || 'Select4') {
            jQuery.each(element2, function (index, elementId) {
            jQuery('#' + elementId).filter('.'+'formshow').removeClass('formshow'); 
            jQuery('#' + elementId).addClass('formshow');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

First, your `||` expressions are incorrect. Yours are evaluated like this

```js
jQuery(this).val() === ('select1' || 'select2')
```

where `'select1' || 'select2'` **always** evaluates to `'select1'`.

Second, you can simply use [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to flip classes. In fact, the same functionality exists on native `classList` with [toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle).

Try something like this with a simple object mapping selection values to the appropriate element collection

```js
const set1 = document.querySelectorAll('#option1, #option2, #option3');
const set2 = document.querySelectorAll('#option2, #option3, #option4');

const valueMap = {
  select1: set1,
  select2: set1,
  select3: set2,
  Select4: set2,
};

document.getElementById('select-1').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  valueMap[e.target.value]?.forEach((opt) => {
    opt.classList.toggle('formshow');
  });
});
```

```css
div[id^=option]{border:1px solid;margin:1rem 0;padding:1rem}.formshow{background-color:green}
```

```html
<p><select id="select-1"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Make a selection</option><option>select1</option><option>select2</option><option>select3</option><option>Select4</option></select></p><div id="option1">Option #1</div><div id="option2">Option #2</div><div id="option3">Option #3</div><div id="option4">Option #4</div>
```

---

The jQuery equivalent would be something like this

```js
const set1 = $('#option1, #option2, #option3');
const set2 = $('#option2, #option3, #option4');

const valueMap = {
  select1: set1,
  select2: set1,
  select3: set2,
  Select4: set2,
};

$('#select-1').on('change', function () {
  valueMap[$(this).val()]?.toggleClass('formshow');
});
```

Comment: Can't really use that. Should have mentioned that this is WordPress, so when I try I get a bunch of 'const' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') errors.

Comment: Wordpress (a server-side PHP application) has absolutely nothing to do with the ability to run JavaScript code. What exactly is generating that error? Everything I've used in this answer runs in modern browsers

Comment: @AdamBell [as you can see](https://caniuse.com/const), `const` is available in all browsers except for IE 6-10. If you need to support particular browser versions, please make that clear in your question. Again, the fact that you run Wordpress has absolutely no bearing on JavaScript code and if you're seeing errors reported, those are not coming from core Wordpress; they must be from some plugin or other static code analysis tool you've failed to mention